# How to tick all checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a gridview control on my form.Its first column is checkboxcolumn  and the other one textboxcolumn.I am populating Textbox columns with some  string values coming from list

like this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < listeList.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = listeList[i];
                }
```

What am i trying to do is to select all the checboxes in the gridview once the user click button How can I do this

Here is what I have tried

```
private void btnselectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

           // row.Cells[0].Value = "true";

            //if (row.Cells[0].Value != ull)
            //{
            //    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value))
            //    {
            //        MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            //    }
            //}

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `row.Cells[0].Value =  true;`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the appropriate cell to `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`:

```
for(int row = 0; row < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    var chkCell = dataGridView1[0, row] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    // read:
    bool isChecked = (bool)chkCell.EditedFormattedValue;
    // assign:
    chkCell.Value = true;
}
```